# HTML header information appearing in body

Tags: php, html, header

I have created a simple webpage, which includes both a header and footer as separate php files, shown below

```
<?php
$PageName = "Home Page";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/header.php";

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/footer.php";?>
```

this is the header

```
<?php
print("<!DOCTYPE html>");
print("<html lang='en-UK'>");
print("<head>");
print("<title>");
print($PageName);
print("");
print("</title>");
print("<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' >");
print("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>");
$CSSRoot = "/MyPage/StyleDefault.css";
print("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=$CSSRoot>");
print("</head>");
print("<body>");
print("<h1>My Page</h1>");?>
```

and footer

```
<?php print("</body></html>");?>
```

but when I view it the header elements appear in the body as shown below

[header information appearing in the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkwW2.png)

I want to make clear this does not, yet, cause any problems, but I want to know what the cause is.

Thanks

EDIT

brain fart moment putting the code in the comments, sorry.

new index

```
    <?php
    $PageName = "Home Page";
    $CSSRoot = "/MyPage/StyleDefault.css";
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/header.php";
?>
    <h1>My Page</h1>
<?php   
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/footer.php";?>
```

new header

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-UK">
<head>
   <title><?php echo $PageName;?></title>
   <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php echo $CSSRoot;?>">
</head>
<body>
```

new footer

```
</body></html>
```

new output

```
<html lang="en-UK"><head></head><body>


   <title>Home Page</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MyPage/StyleDefault.css">

    <h1>My Page</h1>
</body></html>
```

Comment: printing each line in php? why not close it where you dont need it to be called like `<?php print($PageName); ?>` and use html `<title>your title </title>`?

Comment: Did you tried your header and footer codes together without including them in other page ?

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should do this.

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-UK">
<head>
   <title><?php echo $PageName;?></title>
   <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php echo $CSSRoot;?>">
</head>
<body>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

$PageName = "Home Page";
$CSSRoot = "/MyPage/StyleDefault.css";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/header.php";
?>

<h1>My Page</h1>

<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/footer.php";?>
```

**footer.php**

```
</body>
</html>
```

This should work, I don't know why you would want to print all the html tags using php, while you can just output em normal.

Comment: `$CSSRoot` in page? why not in `header.php`?

Comment: I prefer I assigning it on the actual page than header, just incase when some pages are not in the same directory as `header.php`  so its easy to just assign the proper css url

Comment: I just tried you're suggestion, but the problem still shows up, I believe it has something to do with "&#65279;" that appears just after the header element and just before the end

Comment: can you paste your lastest code @FesteringDoubt, because I dont get the problem you getting also try to empty all browser cache

Comment: <?php
 $PageName = "Home Page";
 $CSSRoot = "/MyPage/StyleDefault.css";
 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/header.php";
?>
 <h1>My Page</h1>
<?php 
 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/MyPage/footer.php";
?>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-UK">
<head>
   <title><?php echo $PageName;?></title>
   <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php echo $CSSRoot;?>">
</head>
<body>

Comment: </body></html> needs more characters here

Comment: <html lang="en-UK"><head></head><body>


   <title>Home Page</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MancVicSoc/StyleDefault.css">

 <h1>My Page</h1>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

I beleive I have found the problem, the sources panel in chrome shows that just before the doctype and end body tags are two characters (ie where the header and footer files begin), represented by red dots, according to http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF this is a ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE, I don't know how they appeared and I can't seem to get rid of them, but it seems likely that they are the cause of the problem.

UPDATE

having looked around the prolbem is that the php files where using UFT-8 BOM (byte order mark) which inserted the offending characters, changing it to UTF-8 (which is under encoding in Notepadd++) solved the problem, thanks for all the help